# Gerrit-Trigger is not triggering

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have successfully configured Gerrit-Trigger plugin in Jenkins. I have following versions:

```
Jenkins: 1.543
Gerrit Code Review (2.1.6.1)
```

I configured a verification job by setting all required settings like:

```
Git
 Repositories and branches info
 Additional Behaviours: Strategy for choosing what to build
   Choosing strategy: Gerrit Trigger
Gerrit Event
```

I am also getting the stream event when I upload any commit using below command:

```
$ssh -p 29418 jenkins@<review-server-address> gerrit stream-events
```

However, the verification job is not triggering. I checked the jenkins.log, it says:

```
SEVERE: Gerrit version is null or the empty string.
```

Is this the reason for not triggering the verification job?
Could you please help?

Comment: Hello, doesn't any one have the answer. I can give additional info, when I use 'ssh -p 29418 jenkins@<review-server-address> gerrit version' command, it gives: gerrit: version: not found.

Comment: jenkins.log:Dec 17, 2013 1:14:20 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.version.GerritVersionChecker createVersionNumber
SEVERE: Gerrit version number is null or the empty string.
Dec 17, 2013 1:15:04 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.version.GerritVersionChecker createVersionNumber
SEVERE: Gerrit version number is null or the empty string.

Comment: I fixed the problem. In Gerrit event, when I put branch name, "Path" must be selected. It was "Plain" in the combobox.